# WPF MVVM cannot get the UI to update from a button click

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a simple window with a textbox and a button. The textbox is bound to a ViewModel property called 'Message' and the button is bound to a command 'ClickCommand' using the standard 'RelayCommand'. The idea is that clicking the button will update the text in the TextBox.

Here's the bindings:

```
    <Button x:Name="button"  Command="{Binding ClickCommand}" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="50,245,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox" Text="{Binding Message, Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="50,95,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="650"/>
```

Here's the ViewModel:

```
public class ProgressViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public RelayCommand ClickCommand { get; set; }
    private ProgressModel progress;

    public ProgressModel Progress
    {
        get { return progress; }
        set { progress = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public ProgressViewModel()
    {
        progress = new ProgressModel { Message = "START" };
        ClickCommand = new RelayCommand((p) => UpdateMessage());
    }

    private void UpdateMessage()
    {
        // Gets to here OK ...
        Message = System.DateTime.Now.ToString(); 
    }

    public string Message
    {
        get
        {
            return progress.Message;
        }

        set
        {
            if (progress.Message != value)
            {
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

}
```

Clicking the button will successfully get me as far as UpdateMessage(), however the Message property is not being changed. Even if I put a breakpoint there and step over it the 'Message' value stays at 'START' which is what it was intialised with in the constructor. The setter code does not run, OnPropertyChanged() doesn't fire and so the View doesn't update.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You not set the new value of Message.

```
public string Message
{
    get
    {
        return progress.Message;
    }

    set
    {
        if (progress.Message != value)
        {
            progress.Message = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```